# Why reduce does not give solution for ArcTan[Tan[x]] == x?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Basic question I can't see why now.

This works

```
Simplify[ArcTan[Tan[x]] == x, Assumptions -> -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2]
(*True*)
```

But

```
 Reduce[ArcTan[Tan[x]] == x, x]
 (*Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.*)
```

Adding `Reals` domain does not help. I was expecting that `Reduce` return `-Pi/2 < x < Pi/2`.  Why it did not?

V 12.3.1

Comment: It could be (quote the *Possible Issues* in [doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html#38886635)) "Reduce does not solve equations that depend on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions".

Comment: The seemingly trivial change `Reduce[ArcTan[Tan[x]] == y && y == x, {x, y}, Reals]` give a warning that supports @Silvia's comment. (The change occurred to me because univariate equations sometimes invoke special methods, and adding a dummy variable might trick it into trying something else that would generate conditions.)

Comment: For instance, compare `Reduce[ArcTan[Tan[x]] == y && y == x && FunctionRange[ArcTan[Tan[x]], x, y], {x}, {y}, Reals]` and `Reduce[ArcTan[Tan[x]] == x && FunctionRange[ArcTan[Tan[x]], x, x], {x}, Reals]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Help function says: `Because ArcTan is a multivalued function, tan^-1(tan(x))!=x`

Get your desired result with

```
red = Reduce[{Tan[x] == y, ArcTan[y] == x}, y, Reals]

(*   -(Pi/2) < x < Pi/2 && y == Tan[x]   *)

red // Simplify[#, {Tan[x] == y, ArcTan[y] == x}] &

(*   Pi + 2 x > 0 && 2 x < Pi   *)
```

Done with version "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)"